# Cassandra as input to Hadoop job exception

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

For some reason I'm getting the following exception while trying to use Cassandra as input to Hadoop

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/driver/core/policies/LoadBalancingPolicy
```

Here is the code

```
public class CDriver extends Configured implements Tool{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, Exception
{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    ToolRunner.run(new CDriver(), args);
}

@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String output = args[0];

    Configuration conf = super.getConf();

    Job job = new Job(conf);

    job.setJarByClass(CDriver.class);
    job.setJobName("Cassandra as input");

    ConfigHelper.setInputInitialAddress(conf, "127.0.0.1");
    ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFamily(conf, "basketball", "nba");
    ConfigHelper.setInputPartitioner(conf, "Murmur3Partitioner");
    CqlConfigHelper.setInputCQLPageRowSize(conf, "3");
    job.setInputFormatClass(CqlInputFormat.class);

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(output));

    job.setMapperClass(CMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(CReducer.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    return 0;
}
```

}

It goes off on the following line

```
CqlConfigHelper.setInputCQLPageRowSize(conf, "3");
```

And here are the Maven dependencies:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.nissatech</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestingCassandra</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.nissatech.testingcassandra.CDriver</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>
                            jar-with-dependencies
                        </descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can anyone explain what is the problem? I have Cassandra running on localhost.

Comment: How do you submit job to hadoop?

Comment: I've tried in NetBeans and in pseudo-distributed mode using hadoop jar TestingCassandra-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /user/pera/testingcassandra/output with a fat jar.

Comment: Can you show full pom.xml (or a section regarding fat jar)? Are you sure that all the cassandra deps are in your fat jar?

Comment: I have added the full pom.xml, thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Datastax Java Driver as third party dependency in your `pom.xml`, too. See https://github.com/datastax/java-driver#maven. If you have it as a transitive dependency, make sure you are using the right version of it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But shouldn't that already be included? If you look at mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all/… you can see that it exists as dependency for the jar that I'm including. I tried what you suggested and the strange thing that happens as result is - in NetBeans I get a new exception instead - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: you must set the keyspace and columnfamily with setInputColumnFamily(), while when running in pseudo-distributed mode I get the same exception, even thought I have added the dependency and rebuild project?

Comment: It sounds as if your dependencies depend on different versions of Datastax Cassandra driver. Have you checked if you have multiple transitive dependencies on the driver with different versions?

Comment: Well, I think not. What's the best way to check that out? I followed this one http://gerrymcnicol.com/index.php/2014/01/21/hadoop-and-cassandra-part-7-modifying-your-mapreduce-code-to-read-and-write-from-cassandra/ step by step and this error ocured...

Comment: Have you tried executing `mvn dependency:tree` on command line? If it lists the driver multiple times with different versions that's the issue.

Comment: I did that, but there's no driver until I add it to dependency and then appears only once, so it shouldn't be duplicated. Could there be some problems with Cassandra installed, like different version of it and the libraries? The Cassandra I'm running I download from PlanetCassandra, DataStax version, maybe I should add some other dependencies? Btw, Cassandra works fine from terminal or from DataCenter...

Comment: I also checked on Maven (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all/2.1.5) cassandra-all lists this driver-core, but it isn't pulled from the server. Also, to be sure, I added 2.0.9.2 version, which is listed, but I still get the exception you must set the keyspace and columnfamily with setInputColumnFamily(). It's like it doesn't register that I have already set the keyspace and columnfamily?

Comment: Yeah, then I don't have any idea... :-/